# Access Secure Store credentials from 32bit Application

Tags: visual-studio, secure-store

I am trying to get some Secure Store credentials from SharePoint via a Visual Studio Extension but I am having an issue with the fact that Visual Studio is 32bit and SharePoint is 64bit. The examples on MSDN do not work

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394459.aspx
 - Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService.Server.SecureStoreServiceException: Unable to obtain the local SPFarm.

http://blog.mikehacker.net/2010/01/20/sharepoint-2010-retrieving-credentials-from-secure-store-service/
 - System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The Web application at http://phill-laptop/ could not be found. Verify that you have typed the URL correctly. If the URL should be serving existing content, the system administrator may need to add a new request URL mapping to the intended application.

*I have managed to create a x64 console application and it both examples work beautifully, but I need this to work from Visual Studio.

I have had a look at the SecureStore web service but that doesn't seem to give me the methods I need.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Why do you feel the need to access the Secure Store from outside of SharePoint? Can you provide some background on what you are trying to implement.

Answer (score 1):

You need some sort of bridge to connect the two. See the Stack Overflow question [Calling 32bit Code from 64bit Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128445/calling-32bit-code-from-64bit-process) which talks about interprocess communication. They also point to [this blog post](http://blog.mattmags.com/2007/06/30/accessing-32-bit-dlls-from-64-bit-code/) which explains the whole thing.

It probably won't help you for a Visual Studio extension, but the obvious workaround is to write your own custom web service and call that instead.